# LIKE but NOT LIKE

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table filled with company code prefixes (cp-partnum,ag-partnum,ff-partnum). I would like to select all codes which begin with 'cp-partnum' where partnum does not begin with 'I' or 'i'. So 'cp-aaa' is acceptable but 'cp-iaa' is not. How can this be achieved?

edit: to be clear, I would like ONLY the codes that begin with 'cp-[letter where letter is not "I" or "i"]'

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-predsiimilarto) and a (SQL) regular expression:

```
yourcolumn SIMILAR TO 'cp-[^iI]%'
```

If company are always 2 (alpha) characters, you can do something like:

```
yourcolumn SIMILAR TO '[:ALPHA:]{2}-[^iI]%'
```

If company code can be any two characters, you can use

```
yourcolumn SIMILAR TO '__-[^iI]%'
```

For more complex patterns, study the documentation. `SIMILAR TO` is available starting with Firebird 2.5.

Comment: I am using https://www.fishbowlinventory.com/ which apparently does not support 2.5.

Comment: @DanSerio You'd need to ask fishbowl if it is possible to upgrade to Firebird 2.5 or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use below query:

```
select *
from companies 
where company_code like '__-%' 
and company_code not like '__-I%' 
and company_code not like '__-i%'
```

Comment: I have multiple companys.(ag-,ca-,etc)

Comment: Yes. This query will fetch all the codes with ag-,ca-, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SUBSTRING`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-substring) and `NOT IN` with only 1 `LIKE` :

```
WHERE YourColumn LIKE 'cp-%'
  AND SUBSTRING(YourColumn from 4 for 1) NOT IN('i','l')
```

Comment: You will need to use 4 instead of 3. See [`SUBSTRING`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-substring), the position is 1-based (like (almost?) everything in the SQL standard).

Comment: Yea but the `FROM` got me confused a little.. Didn't know if its from 3 including 3 or from 3 and forwards @MarkRotteveel

Comment: See this quote from the doc: _"This function returns the substring starting at character position `startpos` (the first position being 1)."_

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
where col like 'cp-%' and
      col not like 'cp-l%' and
      col not like 'cp-i%'
```

For multiple prefixes:

```
where left(col, 2) in ('cp', 'ag', 'ff') and
      substring(col, 4, 1) not in ('l', 'i') and
      col like '__-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I did not need to support lower case letters so the following worked.

```
SELECT * FROM product 
WHERE product.num LIKE 'CP-%'
AND product.num NOT IN (SELECT product.num FROM product 
    WHERE product.num LIKE 'CP-I%')
```

Comment: That is highly inefficient, you could also just do `where product.num like 'CP-%' and product.num not like 'CP-I%'`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That was the first thing I tried. I recieved and error for some reason.